# Since 1856, has there ever been a US presidential election where every state votes for the same party in 2 consecutive presidential elections?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

I was thinking about presidential elections in the USA. Since the two major parties existed in any way shape or form, has every state voted the same in consecutive presidential elections? In other words, has the map been totally static?

My guess is no.

Answer (score 9):

To complement Brian Z's [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/54909/28994) with some data - indeed, this has never happened. The years which saw the fewest states switch were 2012, with Indiana & North Carolina switching to the Republican party, and 1888, which saw Indiana and New York go blue.

The years which saw the most states switch were 1932, with 34 states voting differently compared to the last election, and 1968, with 35 changes.

In terms of which state switches most/least frequently - since 1856, Alaska has only switched party twice - in 1964 to Democrat, and then back to Republican in 1968. In contrast, New York and Wisconsin have both switched party 18 times; New York in 1856, 1868, 1872, 1876, 1880, 1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 1912, 1916, 1932, 1948, 1960, 1972, 1976, 1980, and 1988, and Wisconsin in 1856, 1892, 1896, 1912, 1916, 1924, 1928, 1932, 1944, 1948, 1952, 1964, 1968, 1976, 1980, 1988, 2016, and 2020.

[image]

Full Data:

```
--- 2020 ---
Year: 2016 -> 2020
Georgia: R -> D
Arizona: R -> D
Michigan: R -> D
Pennsylvania: R -> D
Wisconsin: R -> D
Total changes: 5
--- 2016 ---
Year: 2012 -> 2016
Florida: D -> R
Iowa: D -> R
Michigan: D -> R
Ohio: D -> R
Pennsylvania: D -> R
Wisconsin: D -> R
Total changes: 6
--- 2012 ---
Year: 2008 -> 2012
Indiana: D -> R
North Carolina: D -> R
Total changes: 2
--- 2008 ---
Year: 2004 -> 2008
Colorado: R -> D
Florida: R -> D
Indiana: R -> D
Iowa: R -> D
Nevada: R -> D
New Mexico: R -> D
North Carolina: R -> D
Ohio: R -> D
Virginia: R -> D
Total changes: 9
--- 2004 ---
Year: 2000 -> 2004
Iowa: D -> R
New Hampshire: R -> D
New Mexico: D -> R
Total changes: 3
--- 2000 ---
Year: 1996 -> 2000
Arizona: D -> R
Arkansas: D -> R
Florida: D -> R
Kentucky: D -> R
Louisiana: D -> R
Missouri: D -> R
Nevada: D -> R
New Hampshire: D -> R
Ohio: D -> R
Tennessee: D -> R
West Virginia: D -> R
Total changes: 11
--- 1996 ---
Year: 1992 -> 1996
Arizona: R -> D
Colorado: D -> R
Florida: R -> D
Georgia: D -> R
Montana: D -> R
Total changes: 5
--- 1992 ---
Year: 1988 -> 1992
Arkansas: R -> D
California: R -> D
Colorado: R -> D
Connecticut: R -> D
Delaware: R -> D
Georgia: R -> D
Illinois: R -> D
Kentucky: R -> D
Louisiana: R -> D
Maine: R -> D
Maryland: R -> D
Michigan: R -> D
Missouri: R -> D
Montana: R -> D
Nevada: R -> D
New Hampshire: R -> D
New Jersey: R -> D
New Mexico: R -> D
Ohio: R -> D
Pennsylvania: R -> D
Tennessee: R -> D
Vermont: R -> D
Total changes: 22
--- 1988 ---
Year: 1984 -> 1988
Hawaii: R -> D
Iowa: R -> D
Massachusetts: R -> D
New York: R -> D
Oregon: R -> D
Rhode Island: R -> D
Washington: R -> D
West Virginia: R -> D
Wisconsin: R -> D
Total changes: 9
--- 1984 ---
Year: 1980 -> 1984
Georgia: D -> R
Hawaii: D -> R
Maryland: D -> R
Rhode Island: D -> R
West Virginia: D -> R
Total changes: 5
--- 1980 ---
Year: 1976 -> 1980
Alabama: D -> R
Arkansas: D -> R
Delaware: D -> R
Florida: D -> R
Kentucky: D -> R
Louisiana: D -> R
Massachusetts: D -> R
Mississippi: D -> R
Missouri: D -> R
New York: D -> R
North Carolina: D -> R
Ohio: D -> R
Pennsylvania: D -> R
South Carolina: D -> R
Tennessee: D -> R
Texas: D -> R
Wisconsin: D -> R
Total changes: 17
--- 1976 ---
Year: 1972 -> 1976
Alabama: R -> D
Arkansas: R -> D
Delaware: R -> D
Florida: R -> D
Georgia: R -> D
Hawaii: R -> D
Kentucky: R -> D
Louisiana: R -> D
Maryland: R -> D
Minnesota: R -> D
Mississippi: R -> D
Missouri: R -> D
New York: R -> D
North Carolina: R -> D
Ohio: R -> D
Pennsylvania: R -> D
Rhode Island: R -> D
South Carolina: R -> D
Tennessee: R -> D
Texas: R -> D
West Virginia: R -> D
Wisconsin: R -> D
Total changes: 22
--- 1972 ---
Year: 1968 -> 1972
Alabama: AI -> R
Arkansas: AI -> R
Connecticut: D -> R
Georgia: AI -> R
Hawaii: D -> R
Louisiana: AI -> R
Maine: D -> R
Maryland: D -> R
Michigan: D -> R
Minnesota: D -> R
Mississippi: AI -> R
New York: D -> R
Pennsylvania: D -> R
Rhode Island: D -> R
Texas: D -> R
Washington: D -> R
West Virginia: D -> R
Total changes: 17
--- 1968 ---
Year: 1964 -> 1968
Alabama: R -> AI
Alaska: D -> R
Arkansas: D -> AI
California: D -> R
Colorado: D -> R
Delaware: D -> R
Florida: D -> R
Georgia: R -> AI
Idaho: D -> R
Illinois: D -> R
Indiana: D -> R
Iowa: D -> R
Kansas: D -> R
Kentucky: D -> R
Louisiana: R -> AI
Mississippi: R -> AI
Missouri: D -> R
Montana: D -> R
Nebraska: D -> R
Nevada: D -> R
New Hampshire: D -> R
New Jersey: D -> R
New Mexico: D -> R
North Carolina: D -> R
North Dakota: D -> R
Ohio: D -> R
Oklahoma: D -> R
Oregon: D -> R
South Dakota: D -> R
Tennessee: D -> R
Utah: D -> R
Vermont: D -> R
Virginia: D -> R
Wisconsin: D -> R
Wyoming: D -> R
Total changes: 35
--- 1964 ---
Year: 1960 -> 1964
Alabama: I -> R
Alaska: R -> D
California: R -> D
Colorado: R -> D
First election in D.C.: D
Florida: R -> D
Georgia: D -> R
Idaho: R -> D
Indiana: R -> D
Iowa: R -> D
Kansas: R -> D
Kentucky: R -> D
Louisiana: D -> R
Maine: R -> D
Mississippi: I -> R
Montana: R -> D
Nebraska: R -> D
New Hampshire: R -> D
North Dakota: R -> D
Ohio: R -> D
Oklahoma: R -> D
Oregon: R -> D
South Carolina: D -> R
South Dakota: R -> D
Tennessee: R -> D
Utah: R -> D
Vermont: R -> D
Virginia: R -> D
Washington: R -> D
Wisconsin: R -> D
Wyoming: R -> D
Total changes: 31
--- 1960 ---
Year: 1956 -> 1960
Alabama: D -> I
First election in Alaska: R
Connecticut: R -> D
Delaware: R -> D
First election in Hawaii: D
Illinois: R -> D
Louisiana: R -> D
Maryland: R -> D
Massachusetts: R -> D
Michigan: R -> D
Minnesota: R -> D
Mississippi: D -> I
Nevada: R -> D
New Jersey: R -> D
New Mexico: R -> D
New York: R -> D
Pennsylvania: R -> D
Rhode Island: R -> D
Texas: R -> D
West Virginia: R -> D
Total changes: 20
--- 1956 ---
Year: 1952 -> 1956
Kentucky: D -> R
Louisiana: D -> R
Missouri: R -> D
West Virginia: D -> R
Total changes: 4
--- 1952 ---
Year: 1948 -> 1952
Alabama: SR -> D
Arizona: D -> R
California: D -> R
Colorado: D -> R
Florida: D -> R
Idaho: D -> R
Illinois: D -> R
Iowa: D -> R
Louisiana: SR -> D
Massachusetts: D -> R
Minnesota: D -> R
Mississippi: SR -> D
Missouri: D -> R
Montana: D -> R
Nevada: D -> R
New Mexico: D -> R
Ohio: D -> R
Oklahoma: D -> R
Rhode Island: D -> R
South Carolina: SR -> D
Tennessee: D -> R
Texas: D -> R
Utah: D -> R
Virginia: D -> R
Washington: D -> R
Wisconsin: D -> R
Wyoming: D -> R
Total changes: 27
--- 1948 ---
Year: 1944 -> 1948
Alabama: D -> SR
Colorado: R -> D
Connecticut: D -> R
Delaware: D -> R
Iowa: R -> D
Louisiana: D -> SR
Maryland: D -> R
Michigan: D -> R
Mississippi: D -> SR
New Hampshire: D -> R
New Jersey: D -> R
New York: D -> R
Ohio: R -> D
Oregon: D -> R
Pennsylvania: D -> R
South Carolina: D -> SR
Wisconsin: R -> D
Wyoming: R -> D
Total changes: 18
--- 1944 ---
Year: 1940 -> 1944
Michigan: R -> D
Ohio: D -> R
Wisconsin: D -> R
Wyoming: D -> R
Total changes: 4
--- 1940 ---
Year: 1936 -> 1940
Colorado: D -> R
Indiana: D -> R
Iowa: D -> R
Kansas: D -> R
Michigan: D -> R
Nebraska: D -> R
North Dakota: D -> R
South Dakota: D -> R
Total changes: 8
--- 1936 ---
Year: 1932 -> 1936
Connecticut: R -> D
Delaware: R -> D
New Hampshire: R -> D
Pennsylvania: R -> D
Total changes: 4
--- 1932 ---
Year: 1928 -> 1932
Arizona: R -> D
California: R -> D
Colorado: R -> D
Florida: R -> D
Idaho: R -> D
Illinois: R -> D
Indiana: R -> D
Iowa: R -> D
Kansas: R -> D
Kentucky: R -> D
Maryland: R -> D
Michigan: R -> D
Minnesota: R -> D
Missouri: R -> D
Montana: R -> D
Nebraska: R -> D
Nevada: R -> D
New Jersey: R -> D
New Mexico: R -> D
New York: R -> D
North Carolina: R -> D
North Dakota: R -> D
Ohio: R -> D
Oklahoma: R -> D
Oregon: R -> D
South Dakota: R -> D
Tennessee: R -> D
Texas: R -> D
Utah: R -> D
Virginia: R -> D
Washington: R -> D
West Virginia: R -> D
Wisconsin: R -> D
Wyoming: R -> D
Total changes: 34
--- 1928 ---
Year: 1924 -> 1928
Florida: D -> R
Massachusetts: R -> D
North Carolina: D -> R
Oklahoma: D -> R
Rhode Island: R -> D
Tennessee: D -> R
Texas: D -> R
Virginia: D -> R
Wisconsin: PR -> R
Total changes: 9
--- 1924 ---
Year: 1920 -> 1924
Kentucky: D -> R
Oklahoma: R -> D
Tennessee: R -> D
Wisconsin: R -> PR
Total changes: 4
--- 1920 ---
Year: 1916 -> 1920
Arizona: D -> R
California: D -> R
Colorado: D -> R
Idaho: D -> R
Kansas: D -> R
Maryland: D -> R
Missouri: D -> R
Montana: D -> R
Nebraska: D -> R
Nevada: D -> R
New Hampshire: D -> R
New Mexico: D -> R
North Dakota: D -> R
Ohio: D -> R
Oklahoma: D -> R
Tennessee: D -> R
Utah: D -> R
Washington: D -> R
Wyoming: D -> R
Total changes: 19
--- 1916 ---
Year: 1912 -> 1916
California: PR -> D
Connecticut: D -> R
Delaware: D -> R
Illinois: D -> R
Indiana: D -> R
Iowa: D -> R
Maine: D -> R
Massachusetts: D -> R
Michigan: PR -> R
Minnesota: PR -> R
New Jersey: D -> R
New York: D -> R
Oregon: D -> R
Pennsylvania: PR -> R
Rhode Island: D -> R
South Dakota: PR -> R
Utah: R -> D
Washington: PR -> D
West Virginia: D -> R
Wisconsin: D -> R
Total changes: 20
--- 1912 ---
Year: 1908 -> 1912
First election in Arizona: D
California: R -> PR
Connecticut: R -> D
Delaware: R -> D
Idaho: R -> D
Illinois: R -> D
Indiana: R -> D
Iowa: R -> D
Kansas: R -> D
Maine: R -> D
Massachusetts: R -> D
Michigan: R -> PR
Minnesota: R -> PR
Missouri: R -> D
Montana: R -> D
New Hampshire: R -> D
New Jersey: R -> D
First election in New Mexico: D
New York: R -> D
North Dakota: R -> D
Ohio: R -> D
Oregon: R -> D
Pennsylvania: R -> PR
Rhode Island: R -> D
South Dakota: R -> PR
Washington: R -> PR
West Virginia: R -> D
Wisconsin: R -> D
Wyoming: R -> D
Total changes: 29
--- 1908 ---
Year: 1904 -> 1908
Colorado: R -> D
Nebraska: R -> D
Nevada: R -> D
First election in Oklahoma: D
Total changes: 4
--- 1904 ---
Year: 1900 -> 1904
Colorado: D -> R
Idaho: D -> R
Maryland: R -> D
Missouri: D -> R
Montana: D -> R
Nevada: D -> R
Total changes: 6
--- 1900 ---
Year: 1896 -> 1900
Kansas: D -> R
Kentucky: R -> D
Nebraska: D -> R
South Dakota: D -> R
Utah: D -> R
Washington: D -> R
Wyoming: D -> R
Total changes: 7
--- 1896 ---
Year: 1892 -> 1896
California: D -> R
Colorado: PO -> D
Connecticut: D -> R
Delaware: D -> R
Idaho: PO -> D
Illinois: D -> R
Indiana: D -> R
Kansas: PO -> D
Kentucky: D -> R
Maryland: D -> R
Montana: R -> D
Nebraska: R -> D
Nevada: PO -> D
New Jersey: D -> R
New York: D -> R
North Dakota: SP -> R
South Dakota: R -> D
First election in Utah: D
Washington: R -> D
West Virginia: D -> R
Wisconsin: D -> R
Wyoming: R -> D
Total changes: 22
--- 1892 ---
Year: 1888 -> 1892
California: R -> D
Colorado: R -> PO
First election in Idaho: PO
Illinois: R -> D
Indiana: R -> D
Kansas: R -> PO
First election in Montana: R
Nevada: R -> PO
New York: R -> D
First election in North Dakota: SP
First election in South Dakota: R
First election in Washington: R
Wisconsin: R -> D
First election in Wyoming: R
Total changes: 14
--- 1888 ---
Year: 1884 -> 1888
Indiana: D -> R
New York: D -> R
Total changes: 2
--- 1884 ---
Year: 1880 -> 1884
California: D -> R
Connecticut: R -> D
Indiana: R -> D
Nevada: D -> R
New York: R -> D
Total changes: 5
--- 1880 ---
Year: 1876 -> 1880
California: R -> D
Connecticut: D -> R
Florida: R -> D
Indiana: D -> R
Louisiana: R -> D
Nevada: R -> D
New York: D -> R
South Carolina: R -> D
Total changes: 8
--- 1876 ---
Year: 1872 -> 1876
Alabama: R -> D
Arkansas: R -> D
First election in Colorado: R
Connecticut: R -> D
Delaware: R -> D
Indiana: R -> D
Mississippi: R -> D
New Jersey: R -> D
New York: R -> D
North Carolina: R -> D
Virginia: R -> D
West Virginia: R -> D
Total changes: 12
--- 1872 ---
Year: 1868 -> 1872
Delaware: D -> R
Louisiana: D -> R
First election in Mississippi: R
Missouri: R -> D
New Jersey: D -> R
New York: D -> R
Oregon: D -> R
Tennessee: R -> D
First election in Texas: D
First election in Virginia: R
Total changes: 10
--- 1868 ---
Year: 1864 -> 1868
First election in Alabama: R
First election in Arkansas: R
First election in Florida: R
First election in Georgia: D
Louisiana: R -> D
Maryland: R -> D
First election in Nebraska: R
New York: R -> D
First election in North Carolina: R
Oregon: R -> D
First election in South Carolina: R
Total changes: 11
--- 1864 ---
Year: 1860 -> 1864
Delaware: SD -> D
First election in Kansas: R
Kentucky: CU -> D
Louisiana: SD -> R
Maryland: SD -> R
Missouri: ND -> R
First election in Nevada: R
New Jersey: R -> D
Tennessee: CU -> R
First election in West Virginia: R
Total changes: 10
--- 1860 ---
Year: 1856 -> 1860
Alabama: D -> SD
Arkansas: D -> SD
California: D -> R
Delaware: D -> SD
Florida: D -> SD
Georgia: D -> SD
Illinois: D -> R
Indiana: D -> R
Kentucky: D -> CU
Louisiana: D -> SD
Maryland: KN -> SD
First election in Minnesota: R
Mississippi: D -> SD
Missouri: D -> ND
New Jersey: D -> R
North Carolina: D -> SD
First election in Oregon: R
Pennsylvania: D -> R
South Carolina: D -> SD
Tennessee: D -> CU
Texas: D -> SD
Virginia: D -> CU
Total changes: 22
--- 1856 ---
Year: 1852 -> 1856
Connecticut: D -> R
Iowa: D -> R
Kentucky: W -> D
Maine: D -> R
Maryland: D -> KN
Massachusetts: W -> R
Michigan: D -> R
New Hampshire: D -> R
New York: D -> R
Ohio: D -> R
Rhode Island: D -> R
Tennessee: W -> D
Vermont: W -> R
Wisconsin: D -> R
Total changes: 14
```

Answer (score 5):

**No** the US electoral map has never been exactly the same two presidential elections in a row. You can see for yourself on 270towin.com, [here](https://www.270towin.com/historical-presidential-elections/timeline/) and [here](https://www.270towin.com/historical-presidential-elections/).